# Do I need to install Ubuntu OS on my PC to host a website with​ my VPS?

Tags: vps

When researching hosting a website on a VPS notice that all of the tutorials use Ubuntu in their example. I want to host my website on VPS but I do not have experience with Ubuntu. Can I host my website on a VPS running Windows?

Comment: Are you sure your internet uplink is fast enough to run a website?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to install Ubuntu OS on my PC to host a website with​ my VPS?

No, you can use a different OS on desktop and VPS.

> Can I host my website on a VPS running Windows?

Yes, but this is probably not what you want. The costs will be higher and as a beginner you are probably better off using what the majority use, so you can follow along using all the tutorials you found.

Many people administer an Ubuntu VPS from their Windows or Mac machines. You can control it using text commands in a terminal using something like [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/), or you can try to find a VPS provider offering preinstalled applications that you manage using your web browser.

If you do choose to install Ubuntu on your PC you may find that it is easier to administer the VPS, and that you have greater functionality since both PC and server are the same OS, but it is a steep learning curve at first.

Try following [this guide on DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-log-into-a-vps-with-putty-windows-users) from your Windows PC first, that's a good starting point.

Comment: Nice solid answer! Windows on the home computer is just fine. For the VPS, I highly recommend a linux install of some sort. I would assume many web hosts have install images ready to go. That would be best. Linux is not that hard to learn and does not require extensive knowledge to begin. However, I agree that there is a bit of steep curve since it is so different from Windows. This is why cPanel has been so successful. It really does make things a lot simpler. The OP should be looking for a host that will install a secure version of Linux with cPanel which is a fairly typical option. Cheers!!